# Cannot create new Android project in Eclipse

Tags: android, eclipse

When I try to create a new project in Eclipse, I am getting the following error:

```
[2016-06-20 00:49:49 - Activitybasic] C:\Users\AKHIL\Documents\Android\Activitybasic\res\values\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2016-06-20 00:49:49 - Activitybasic] 
[2016-06-20 00:49:49 - Activitybasic] C:\Users\AKHIL\Documents\Android\Activitybasic\res\values-v11\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2016-06-20 00:49:49 - Activitybasic] 
[2016-06-20 00:49:49 - Activitybasic] C:\Users\AKHIL\Documents\Android\Activitybasic\res\values-v14\styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.
[2016-06-20 00:49:49 - Activitybasic] 
[2016-06-20 00:49:49 - basics] C:\Users\AKHIL\Documents\Android\basics\res\values\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2016-06-20 00:49:49 - basics] 
[2016-06-20 00:49:49 - basics] C:\Users\AKHIL\Documents\Android\basics\res\values-v11\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2016-06-20 00:49:49 - basics] 
[2016-06-20 00:49:49 - basics] C:\Users\AKHIL\Documents\Android\basics\res\values-v14\styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.
[2016-06-20 00:49:49 - basics] 
[2016-06-20 00:49:50 - testing] C:\Users\AKHIL\Documents\Android\testing\res\values\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2016-06-20 00:49:50 - testing] 
[2016-06-20 00:49:50 - testing] C:\Users\AKHIL\Documents\Android\testing\res\values-v11\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2016-06-20 00:49:50 - testing] 
[2016-06-20 00:49:50 - testing] C:\Users\AKHIL\Documents\Android\testing\res\values-v14\styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.
[2016-06-20 00:49:50 - testing] 
[2016-06-20 00:53:26 - Activitybasic] C:\Users\AKHIL\Documents\Android\Activitybasic\res\values\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2016-06-20 00:53:26 - Activitybasic] 
[2016-06-20 00:53:26 - Activitybasic] C:\Users\AKHIL\Documents\Android\Activitybasic\res\values-v11\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2016-06-20 00:53:26 - Activitybasic] 
[2016-06-20 00:53:26 - Activitybasic] C:\Users\AKHIL\Documents\Android\Activitybasic\res\values-v14\styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.
[2016-06-20 00:53:26 - Activitybasic] 
[2016-06-20 00:55:36 - test2] C:\Users\AKHIL\Documents\Android\test2\res\values\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2016-06-20 00:55:36 - test2] 
[2016-06-20 00:55:36 - test2] C:\Users\AKHIL\Documents\Android\test2\res\values-v11\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2016-06-20 00:55:36 - test2] 
[2016-06-20 00:55:36 - test2] C:\Users\AKHIL\Documents\Android\test2\res\values-v14\styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.
[2016-06-20 00:55:36 - test2] 
[2016-06-20 00:55:38 - test2] C:\Users\AKHIL\Documents\Android\test2\res\values\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2016-06-20 00:55:38 - test2] 
[2016-06-20 00:55:38 - test2] C:\Users\AKHIL\Documents\Android\test2\res\values-v11\styles.xml:7: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light'.
[2016-06-20 00:55:38 - test2] 
[2016-06-20 00:55:38 - test2] C:\Users\AKHIL\Documents\Android\test2\res\values-v14\styles.xml:8: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar'.
[2016-06-20 00:55:38 - test2]
```

Comment: You shoud not use eclipse, use Android Studio https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html

Answer (score 0):

You can try either of these solutions:
- Start using Android Studio instead of eclipse
- change your AppcompatActivity to Activity (say public class MainActivity extends Activity)
- change your app theme to extend AppCompat theme